# How to auto size nodes based on content in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want my nodes to be rectangular, with text content inside the rectangle.  That much I can do, however I would like the rectangle to size appropriately to the width of the text.  Can that be done?

Comment: Your http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is planned for 2.4, but I don't know whether I'll be able to devote the time to it in the near future: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/649